# how to save output of for loop in cmd?

Tags: variables, for-loop, cmd

I am trying to extract packages information from directory .\sam and iterate through all sub directories, some of them is returning packages reference but some is not:

```
C:\Users\mac\Desktop\sample\sam>for /R /D %s in (*) do \users\mac\desktop\jclassinfo\jclassinfo --packages %s\*.class
```

I want to add folder names within the loop, then I try:

```
C:\Users\mac\Desktop\sample\sam>for /R /D %s in (*) do (dir %s /b /s /a:d & \users\mac\desktop\jclassinfo\jclassinfo --packages %s\*.class) >> pack.txt
```

But the pack.txt looks miserable.

My question is any code can do:

1. Save output of packages reference by * folder names? (*.txt)

or

2. better way printing folder names when jclassinfo returning packages? (if?)

Comment: do you really need to iterate twice (`for /R` AND `dir /s`) ?

Comment: i need to keep folders structure just under the .\sam, dir /b only returns the last folder name